# What to do to get Android option in Eclipse under Window-->Preferences

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to android development and a tutorial for it suggests I can get an android option in Eclipse under the Windows->Preferences screen.  How can I actually get that? It wasn't one of the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the Android SDK, installed it, and updated it using the SDK manager.

In Eclipse, go to Help then install new software.

In "Work with" enter the following: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

Put a checkmark in "Developer Tools" (that will grab all of the items, you may not need all, but DDMS an Development Tools are important.

After that just click Yeahohkaywhatever on prompts and should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are complete instructions for working with Android (including Eclipse) on this page...

[Installing the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

Answer (score 1):

assuming you've completed bobe-feh's instructions...your next setup would be to goto the avd manager
(its just below the 'Navigate' option) and setup a new Virtual device. Now your good to go ahead testing your applications